# ¿Por qué no puedo navegar a la siguiente pantalla tocando el botón?

Tags: api, flutter, dart, rest

Este es el botón que captura un código de recuperación recibido a través de gmail.

```
 onPressed: () async {

                  bool? resp = _recoverKey.currentState?.validate();
                    if (resp!) {
                      setState(() {});
          
                      isLoading = true;
                      await _recoverKeycodeController.recuperarCodeclave(
                          _emailTextEditingController.text, context);
                      isLoading = false;
                    }
                  },
```

ok tenemos el siguiente bloque que navega a la siguiente pantalla para ingresar la nueva contraseña, aquí viajará en base a la respuesta obtenida.

```
class RecoverKeyController {
  final RecoverKeycodeService _recoverKeycodeService = RecoverKeycodeService();
  recuperarCodeclave(String codigoRecuperacion, BuildContext context) async {
    List datos;
    datos = await _recoverKeycodeService.ingresarcodigo(codigoRecuperacion);
    print(datos);
    if (datos[0]) {
      print('proceso exitoso $datos');
      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => RecoverNewKeyScreen(idUsuario: datos[1]),
      ));
    } else {
      print('proceso no exitoso $datos');
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: "codigo errado por favor intente nuevamente",
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
          gravity: ToastGravity.TOP,
          timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 16.0);
    }
  }
}
```

( los prints para hacer el debugging no se mostraban en la consola no se porque ) y aqui esta el codigo encargado de realizar el proceso del que les hablo.

```
class RecoverKeycodeService with ChangeNotifier {
  RecoverKeyCodeModel _recoverKeyCodeModel = RecoverKeyCodeModel(
    data: Data(
      codigo: '',
      estado: false,
      id: 0,
      idUsuario: '',
      createdAt: '',
      updatedAt: '',
    ),
    msg: '',
    status: 0,
  );
  Future ingresarcodigo(String codigoRecuperacion) async {
    final isConect = await isConnect();
    if (isConect) {
      // final data = {'correo': correo};
      // print(data);
      //'${Environment.urlApi}/auth/codigoValido/$codigoRecuperacion');
      final url = Uri.parse(
          'https://potapi.espaciocientifico.com/api/auth/validateCode/$codigoRecuperacion');

      final resp = await http.post(url,
          // body: jsonEncode(data),
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  if (resp.statusCode == 200) {
    Map<String, dynamic> codigoService = jsonDecode(resp.body);

    if (codigoService['status'] == 200) {
      return [true, codigoService['data']['idUsuario']];
    } else {
      return [false, 0];
    }
  } else {
    return [false, 0];
  }
}
  }
}
```

Repito de nuevo. Una vez que ingreso el código enviado a través de gmail, que son dígitos numéricos, cuando toco el botón para hacer el proceso, solo me muestra la cantidad de toques que hago en el botón pero no hago el proceso que debería. muchas gracias.

Comment: Pon un breakpoint en la línea de `recuperarCodeclave` para que la ejecución se detenga allí y puedas ejecutar línea por línea para ver qué sucede. En primera instancia, si los logs no se ejecutan es porque nunca se ejecuta `recuperarCodeclave`, lo que quiere decir que la variable `resp` siempre es `false`.

Comment: @gugadev gracias. pues un print debajo de la validacion del formulario y resp era = false por eso nunca se ejecutaba la siguiente linea asi que cambie el formulario para que aceptara los digitos en vez de cadenas de caracteres.

Comment: entonces se solucionó el problema?